# postgreSQL inner join bits

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to display the pistes that are currently open, together with the lifts that are currently operating and that provide access to those pistes.

```
SELECT piste_name,lift_name 
FROM pistes 
INNER JOIN lifts ON pistes.piste_name = lifts.lift_name 
WHERE pistes.open = 1 AND lifts.operating = 1;
```

and there is an error saying:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: bit = integer LINE 1:
>   ...es.piste_name = lifts.lift_name where pistes.open = 1 and li...

Open and operating are both bits so 1 = true?

Answer (score 1):

Cast 1 (which is an integer) to a bit type:

```
WHERE pistes.open = 1::bit
```

Comment: I've got empty rows now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bit string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html):

```
SELECT piste_name,lift_name 
FROM pistes 
INNER JOIN lifts ON pistes.piste_name = lifts.lift_name 
WHERE pistes.open = B'1' AND lifts.operating = B'1';
```

Comment: Please update your answer by adding sample data, and what do you expect as result.

Comment: may be there are now rows in your table meeting the `WHERE` condition,  verify it

Comment: => select piste_name, lift_name from pistes INNER JOIN lifts on pistes.open = lifts.operating;                                                                   
It displays all the data where all the pistes and lifts are operating, but I have to display only these pistes and lifts which are operating together